# AVQueuePlayer not playing sounds

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, avqueueplayer

I don't seem to able to playback sounds using `AVQueuePlayer`. The application compiles and runs fine but i'm not getting any audio when the `imageTouched' method is called. Can anyone help?

```
-(void) imageTouched
{
    NSString * path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSString * path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound2" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];

    AVPlayerItem *firstSound = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url1];
    AVPlayerItem *secondSound = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url2];

    NSArray *sounds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstSound, secondSound, nil];
    AVQueuePlayer *player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:sounds];

    [player play];
    NSLog(@"%d",player.status);

}
```

**EDIT 1:** I've checked to see if there was any problem with the filenames (case, spelling, etc) and there doesn't seem to be. I've been able to play the sounds with the following code but i really need to get `AVQueuePlayer` working. Please help!

```
NSString *path;
SystemSoundID soundId;
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( (CFURLRef)objc_unretainedPointer( url), &soundId);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);
```

Comment: Check that the sound files are actually included in your app bundle and with their file names spelled correctly (including case).

Comment: The sounds are copied to my resources folder and the spelling is correct; unfortunately that's not the problem. My nslog is printing 0 if that's any help

Comment: I should have also mentioned that i can play the sounds fine using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);` but i want to use `AVQueuePlayer`. Is there maybe something i'm missing out in my .h file?

Answer (score 0):

I realise it may be too late for you by now, but I suspect that reason is that the AVQueuePlayer is being autoreleased immediately, so no sound is played. Try `[[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:sounds]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I did nearly the same think but instead of declaring the `AVQueuePlayer *player` in the function, I declared it in the `interface`.